# woocommerce mostrar produtos destaque pela categoria sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

gostaria que esse resultado fosse apenas 1 com todas as formações separada por coluna

e que ela somente aparecesse se existir name = 'Resina' AND name = 'featured' caso contrario nao listar

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] sql

caso eu coloque WHERE b.name = 'featured' and b.name = 'Resinas'
nao me retornar valor

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: `name = 'Resina' AND name = 'featured' ` basicamente vc já tem a solução, coloque isso num `where` na sua query

Comment: se eu faço isso nao me retorna resultado

Comment: E está correto ele não retornar nada

Comment: ele não pode ter os dois nomes ao mesmo tempo

Comment: por isso faz se necessário a utilização do union

Comment: eu preciso que liste somente se os dois existirem caso contrario nao quero que liste

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conseguir resolver pessoal segue abaixo como conseguir resolver

```
Select *
FROM
(
Select d.ID, d.post_title, d.post_type,
MIN(CASE WHEN b.name = 'Resinas' THEN b.name END) AS categoria, 
MIN(CASE WHEN b.name = 'featured' THEN b.name END) AS destaque
from wp_term_taxonomy a
inner join wp_terms b on a.term_id = b.term_id
inner join wp_term_relationships c on a.term_taxonomy_id = c.term_taxonomy_id
inner join wp_posts d on c.object_id = d.id
where b.name IN ('Resinas', 'featured') and d.post_type = 'product'
GROUP BY d.ID
) AS x
WHERE x.destaque = 'featured' AND x.post_type = 'product' AND x.categoria = 'Resinas'
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Coloque a sua pergunta em uma clausula where

Assim:

```
Select d.ID, a.taxonomy, b.name, d.post_title, d.post_type
from wp_term_taxonomy a

inner join wp_terms b on a.term_id = b.term_id
inner join wp_term_relationships c on a.term_taxonomy_id = c.term_taxonomy_id
inner join wp_post d on c.object_id = d.id

where b.name = "Resina"

union

Select d.ID, a.taxonomy, b.name, d.post_title, d.post_type
from wp_term_taxonomy a

inner join wp_terms b on a.term_id = b.term_id
inner join wp_term_relationships c on a.term_taxonomy_id = c.term_taxonomy_id
inner join wp_post d on c.object_id = d.id

where b.name = "featured"
```

Comment: me retornou todos os valores da categoria

Comment: Seria todos que contem esse nome ou pelo menos em alguma parte

Comment: caso queira algo específico tire o like e coloque igual sem o porcento

Comment: assim : where b.name = "featured"

Comment: exato porem ele precisa conter tmb b.name = 'Resinas'

Comment: sim, adicione tambem, tirando o like

Comment: Já conseguir resolver e ja postei obrigado pela ajuda